# Textbox overlays with Keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, mobility

I have used cordova for my html5 application. Now whenever I am pressing the textbox the keypad appears but this keypad overlays the textbox and my screen is not move to top.

But funny part is this issue happens only once after that installation. Second time onwards whenever I tap on textbox keypad is apparing and screen is moving to top

I am using both focus and blur events like below

```
this.$('#event').on('blur', function() {    
    $('#event').css('height', $(window).height());              
    cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(false);
});
this.$('#event').on('focus', function() {   
    $('#event').css('height', $(window).height());          
    cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(false);
});
```

Comment: Is the use of `this` correct here? It would be safer if you just executed the functions with `$('#event')`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Why do you call `cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(false);` inside the event handlers? Don't you want the scroll to be enabled before the focus/blur event?